# Mocking component methods with jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, enzyme, jestjs

Say I have the following component:

```
export class ExampleComponent extends Component {

    exampleMethod1 = () => {
      console.log('in example 1')
    }

    exampleMethod2 = () => {
      console.log('in example 2')
      this.exampleMethod1()
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity id='touchable' onPress={exampleMethod2}><Text>Touchable</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
}
```

This works exactly how you would expect. The button appears, and can be pressed. Both methods fire, and console log their text.

I now try to test this with jest:

```
describe('example tests', () => {
  let wrapper
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<ExampleComponent/>)
  })

  it('this test fails. Interestingly both messages still print', () => {
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    instance.exampleMethod2 = jest.fn()
    wrapper.find('#touchable').simulate('press')
    //wrapper.update() uncommenting this line has no effect.
    expect(instance.exampleMethod2.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
  })

  it('this test passes. Only the first message prints', () => {
    const instance = wrapper.instnace()
    instance.exampleMethod1 = jest.fn()
    wrapper.find('#touchable').simulate('press')
    expect(instance.exampleMethod1.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

As annotated, the first test fails, and the original message prints, as if I had never mocked out the method. This happens irrespectively of whether `wrapper.update()` is run or not.

Interestingly, if we replace the onPress with a seemingly identical arrow function like so:

`onPress={() => {exampleMethod2()}}`

The test suddenly passes. This whole thing suggest some weird this binding shenanigans (I think?). Any explanation as to what is going on would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test custom methods on component's prototype object, you should use `mount` function from enzyme and use `spyOn` to mock and trace the call to that method.

```
export class ExampleComponent extends Component {

  exampleMethod1 = () => {
    console.log('in example 1');
    this.setState({ example1: true });
  }

  exampleMethod2 = () => {
    console.log('in example 2')
    this.exampleMethod1()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity id='touchable' onPress={exampleMethod2}><Text>Touchable</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
```

}

```
describe('example tests', () => {
  let wrapper
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<ExampleComponent/>)
  })

  afterAll(() => { wrapper = null; })

  it('some desc here', () => {
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    spyOn(instance, 'exampleMethod1').and.callThrough();
    expect(instance.setState).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

})
```